# How to convert Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> to json string

Tags: .net, amazon-dynamodb

In the .Net SDK AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2 v3.7.0.104, is it possible to convert Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> into json string
I'm using dynamo to store objects of different types and get them at once

```
var queryResponse = await _dynamoDbClient.QueryAsync(queryRequest);
List<Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>> c = queryResponse.Items;
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queryResponse.Items);
```